# Rails model with Mongoid Embedded and Standalone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

How would I create a Mongoid model that has the ability to be saved in it's own collection, and be embedded in another document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer: you can't.

When you use an embedded relationship between two Mongoid documents, this is because you *don't* want the child model in its own collection. An embedded document it literally that: embedded in its parent.

I'm not sure if you're new to Mongoid, so what you may actually be looking for is a referenced relationship, which behaves more like a traditional RDBMS relationship, where the child document stores a reference to the parent document's ID. The Mongoid documentation for this starts [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_one).

It's pretty easy to switch between the two, given these embedded models:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  embeds_many :phone_numbers
end

class PhoneNumber
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :area_code
  field :number

  embedded_in :person
end
```

You can just change the `embeds_many` and `embedded_in`, so it becomes:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  has_many :phone_numbers
end

class PhoneNumber
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :area_code
  field :number

  belongs_to :person
end
```

And it will just work. Now you'll be able to do things like query directly for phone numbers with statements like: `PhoneNumber.where(:area_code => "212")`.

Comment: I would like to add that if it is for de-normalization https://github.com/dzello/mongoid_alize should be a good start.

Comment: That gem is amazing @rubish! Nice find!

Comment: I was afraid of that. The reason why I wanted this ability is for temporary upload storage.  The user would upload an image, and it would be stored in the temporary collection, It would then have the ability to be displayed on the create form dynamically.  After they saved the record they were working on, the temporary image would become embedded in that record. (I can't store an embedded item on a document that hasn't been created yet.)  I will just have to create a temporary model to embed the image in. I was just hoping to skip that extra step and store the image model directly.

Comment: Wow, that mongoid_alize gem looks awesome!  It won't solve this exact problem, but I can definitely use it in other places in my application.

Comment: Ah ok! That makes sense. I've been mulling over an almost identical problem now for a few weeks. One thing you could do (which I _haven't_ tried) is create two models, one say `TemporaryUpload` and `UserImage`. Put all the shared functionality into a single module in your `/lib/` and then include that module in both classes. The only difference is one would be embedded and the other referenced. If you need more detail - let me know and i'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm switching to 2 models for the same data, that seems like the way to go to increase query speed when you need just the standalone data